# How to create triangle in table cell for active?

Tags: html, css

My psd is like this

[image: table]

I want to add triangle in table cell only for active sort with css.

But I see this demo.

[image: table]

But I want the triangle to fall in the middle under the table title.

```css
.table-bordered th {
    background-color: #24374a;
    border: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.table-bordered th.active {
    background-color: #041323;
    position: relative;
}

.table-bordered th.active:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f27e0a;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="domainTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="active" onclick="sortTable(0)">دامنه های تجاری</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(1)">دامنه های ارزان قیمت</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(2)">دامنه های ملی</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(3)">دامنه های خدماتی</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(4)">دامنه های کشوری</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: insert your code is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you wanted.

```css
.table-bordered th {
    background-color: #24374a;
    border: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}

.table-bordered th.active {
    background-color: #041323;
    position: relative;
}

.table-bordered th.active:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #f27e0a;
    border-right: 5px solid #f27e0a;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="domainTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="active" onclick="sortTable(0)">دامنه های تجاری</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(1)">دامنه های ارزان قیمت</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(2)">دامنه های ملی</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(3)">دامنه های خدماتی</th>
        <th onclick="sortTable(4)">دامنه های کشوری</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  right: 50%;
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

td {
  border: solid 3px black;
  width: 160px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="triangle"></div>Make Edits accordingly
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```